# Photoshop colorize made area grainy? How to fix?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, noise

I used the colorize brush to recolor an image since Hue/saturation made everything very muddy. Im trying to preserve these nice clean lines here:

[image]

When I successfully changed the color to this:

[image]

Now the area is "grainy" or just not entirely solid color lines. Is there any way to fix this at this point or avoid in the future?

Comment: I would not use a brush at all. Try adding a solid color layer with a blend mode set to Color.

Comment: I decided to check the two images out and the first image (blue), as it is here, has some pretty crazy compression artifacts that become very visible when the hue is shifted to another color. Mostly red and dark blue. The second image is smaller but luckily it seems to have fewer compression artifacts or any weirdness on the blue side. I used `curves adjustment` on it and it definitely seems like the red side has sort of circular brush marks, whereas the blue side is smoother. In general terms; If you want to recolor the whole thing, use `Layer > New adjustment layer > Hue/Saturation...`

Answer (score 0):

As MG_ said, stay away from Colorize setting of a brush. Use this technique instead:

1) Create a new layer and set the blending mode to Color.  There are several other blending mode options that will also cause a color-changing effect.

2) A: Choose your color with a normal brush and start painting.
 -or- B: Fill the layer with selected color. Then create a mask (filled with black) and paint white in the mask to affect the areas you want to alter.

TIP: Also make sure to work in color modes that give you at least 16-bits per channel.  Never work in 8-bit modes unless you are trying to save memory and you are prepared to handle artifacts that often show up when you apply filters, gradients, blends, or other graduated effects.